# Security in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How we can use Sp_Configure. what kind of privelage we can give to run the following query.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1  
RECONFIGURE 
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1 
RECONFIGURE
```

Comment: > Execute permissions on sp_configure with no parameters
> or with only the first parameter are granted to all users by default. To
> execute sp_configure with both parameters to change a configuration
> option or to run the RECONFIGURE statement, you must be granted the
> ALTER SETTINGS server-level permission. The ALTER SETTINGS permission
> is implicitly held by the sysadmin and serveradmin fixed server roles. That quote is taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx)

Comment: SQL Server Books On Line has pretty good documentation of this system stored procedure. I linked the SQL Server 2012 page (because I had it handy), but you should be able to find the one for SQL Server 2008 with a little effort. A list of the [Server Configuration Options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189631) is available there, too.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the [Book Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx)

> Execute permissions on sp_configure with no parameters or with only
>   the first parameter are granted to all users by default. To execute
>   sp_configure with both parameters to change a configuration option or
>   to run the RECONFIGURE statement, you must be granted the ALTER
>   SETTINGS server-level permission. The ALTER SETTINGS permission is
>   implicitly held by the sysadmin and serveradmin fixed server roles.